# Using options_from_collection_for_select with multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I specify multiple attributes from a model, within a `options_from_collection_for_select()`?

For example, instead of

```
options_from_collections_for_select(@batches, :id, :name)
```

outputting:

```
<select ...>
  <option value="{id}">{name}</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I want to output:

```
<select ...>
  <option value="{id}">{id}. {name}</option>
  ...
</select>
```

From the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), i see that it supports another parameter for "default", but I don't want to default. I want to use the `id` as well as the `name` field within my `batch` model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, define a method on your model like this:

```
def id_and_name
  "#{id}. #{name}"
end
```

Then you can do

```
options_from_collections_for_select(@batches, :id, :id_and_name)
```

Comment: works like a charm.  didn't even think about adding a method there in the model.  thanks for that! (i'll accept when the timer to accept runs out)

Answer (score 4):

Well, another way is :

```
options_from_collections_for_select(
  @batches, :id, ->(ob) { "#{ob.id}. #{ob.name}" }
)
```

Comment: I actually prefer this solution over the latter because I will only use this once.  i'd rather not touch my model, and this solution allows me to do so

Comment: @sircapsalot You tried and it worked ?

Comment: I did.  and it does :) did you guess? well done!

Comment: Nah.. not guess. I tried it by reading docs. :)

Comment: This is great, thanks @ArupRakshit